# How can I add 1 to qty if In_array is true using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to add 1 to `session['cart']['qty']` if it's not a new entry and if it is a new item it will just add the item to `session['cart']`.

```php
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $item = array('pid'  =>  $p['productID'],
                  'qty'  =>  1
                );
    $_SESSION['cart'][0] = $item;
} else {
    $item_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], "pid");

    if (in_array($p['productID'], $item_id)) {
        $to_update = 'qty';
        $new_qty = 5;
        $base = $_SESSION['cart']['pid']['qty'];
    } else {
        $count = count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $item = array('pid' => $p['productID'],
                      'qty' => 1
                    );
        $_SESSION['cart'][$count] = $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the $pid as a unique index to track like

```
$pid=$p['productID'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$pid])){
    $item = array(
        'pid'  =>  $pid,
        'qty'  =>  1
    );
    $_SESSION['cart'][$pid] = $item;
}else{
    /*
     * add 1 qty
     */
    if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$pid])) {
        $_SESSION['cart'][$pid]['qty']= ($_SESSION['cart'][$pid]['qty'] +1);
    }
}
```

you cal also use a similar reduce quantity.

Answer (score 0):

You are not changing the session variable. Try this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $item = array('pid'  =>  $p['productID'],
                  'qty'  =>  1
                );
    $_SESSION['cart'][0] = $item;
} else {
    $item_id = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], "pid");

    if (in_array($p['productID'], $item_id)) {
        $new_qty = 5;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$p['productID']]['qty'] += $new_qty;
    } else {
        $count = count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $item = array('pid' => $p['productID'],
                      'qty' => 1
                    );
        $_SESSION['cart'][$count] = $item;
    }
}
```

This line here doesn't make sense.

```
$base = $_SESSION['cart']['pid']['qty'];
```

Multidimensional arrays don't work like that.
You are trying to access the key `qty` from the array `$_SESSION['cart']['pid']`, but that does not exist. Those two keys are siblings.

Comment: thanks for these answer, but there is another problem if I choose to buy 2 products and try to increment qty of 1 product I already added to my cart it won't merge it will create new row

Comment: @EcnerolOdirrag Okay, sure, as long as it the answer you chose works for you!